# Initialise empty array in an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

lets say i have

```
        var form = {
            header: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'textinput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
           selectedImages: []
        }
```

at some point, user will push some images into this `form.selectedImages` i am doing it in this way:`form.selectedImages.push(image)` BUT because my selectedImages is null, push is not working here.
so, how can i initilise an empty array btw, i have tried `selectedImages: new Array()` but not worked too.

Is there anyway i can fix this issue?

thanks.

**UPDATE**

after i initialized this form. i am using  `setState({form: form})` to set this form to the state. after set is done, `form.selectedImages: null`, `console.log(form)` says..

**UPDATE 2**
here is the full react code:

```
 var form = {
            header: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'textinput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
            description: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'textinput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
            provinence: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'dropdowninput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
            district: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'dropdowninput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
            quarter: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'dropdowninput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
            address: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'textinput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
            where: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'dropdowninput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
            to: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'dropdowninput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
            deliverTo: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'dropdowninput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
            selectedImages: [],
            whatsappContact: false,
            emailContact: false,
            isFree: false
        }
```

this is how i use this form i a switch case. i have n category, and they all have different kind of input information. so created a function, called `initializeFormState()` where basically i get related category info from state and making nullable objects which i don't need based on selected category. at the end,i set this form inputs to the state in order to validate and push them to the server.

this is one of my cases:

```
            case 0: //emlak
                form.where = null;
                form.to = null;
                form.address = null;
                deliverTo = null;
                this.setState({ ...form, selectedImages: [] }, () =>{console.log(form)});
```

Comment: `selectedImages` isn't `null`, it's an empty array `[]`. What is the actual error message you're getting when you try to push to it?

Comment: That should work, can you show some more code?

Comment: and how is this `selectedImages: []` wrong? it initializes an empty array normally, it's not null

Comment: it is working fine.Just update your code and the error log

Comment: you already initialized it with an empty array like this: selectedImages: []
what is the problem?

Comment: bro work to try to use in console the in-browser it woks fine

Comment: Hello everyone, could you please check my updated question?

Comment: Still not getting it, are you doing setState({form: form }) where form equals to the one you posted?

Comment: `setState` is not a JavaScript feature, but it's probably provided by some library (my guess is React). React has 2 variants of `setState`, one is provided by `Component`, one as a `hook`. They differ in how they work. The first one updates state, the latter one replaces it. Please provide information on what you use and how you expect `setState` to behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, You can directly initialize `object` or `array` via passing empty records like `{}` or `[]`.

Your code is right, you don't need to do anything now. just try to push images in the `selectedImages`.

```
form.selectedImages.push(image)
```

It will work.

**UPDATE**
In order to make it working, You have to set state via below command.

```
if(!Array.isArray(form.selectedImages)) form.selectedImages = [];
this.setState({form: form});
```

Comment: Hello again, i have tried what you have suggested. the thing is, before `setState` and after `setState`,  `form.selectedImages = null`.

Comment: I guess the problem with this line `this.setState({ ...form, selectedImages: [] }, () =>{console.log(form)});`. It should be `this.setState({ ...form, selectedImages: [] }, () =>{console.log(this.state)});`.

Answer (score 1):

`[]`, like you did, will initialize an empty array. `Array.push` is available on form.selectedImages. If you run into issue, it's probably something else.

An empty array (`[]`) is not `null`, and is actually truthy (`Boolean([])` equals `true`).

```js
        var form = {
            header: {
                value: null,
                isValid: false,
                type: 'textinput',
                rules: {
                    isRequired: true,
                },
            },
           selectedImages: []
        }
        
document.write(form.selectedImages);
form.selectedImages.push('foo')
document.write(form.selectedImages);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have initialized like this : `form.selectedImages = []`
you can not have the error that it's null when you try the push method

Now if you want to make sure that the table is not empty when you want to push use this:

```
form.selectedImages = [...image]
```